# How to make cascading dropdown with checkbox using jquery-ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown, bootstrap-multiselect

Trying to make cascading dropdown (country,state,city) using jquery ajax
I have used David Stutzs multiselect jquery.
On change of country I am getting state's list from controller using jquery ajax and changing state's options.
I am able to get state's list from controller based on country but 
$('#state').html(state); is not changing state's content.

when I dont write $('#state').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            }); at the start but after $('#state').html(state); it works once.

I guess after applying this $('#state').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            }); content of state is not being changed.

```
    <body>
<div>
    <select id="country" name="country" multiple="multiple">
        @if (ViewBag.country != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in ViewBag.country)
            {
                <option>@item</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
    <select id="state" name="state" multiple="multiple">

    </select>
</div>

<br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="countrycontent">

</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="statecontent">

</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //to enable multiselect dropdown with checkboxes
        $('#country').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
        $('#state').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });

        //invokes when change event happens on country dropdown
        $('#country').on('change', function () {
            var selected = $("#country option:selected");
            var message = "";
            var country = [];
            var i = 0;


            selected.each(function () {
                country[i] = $(this).val();//gets selected countries
                i++;
            });

            if (country != null) {
                //gets states based on selected countries
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '../Home/GetState',
                    data: { country },
                    success: function (result) {
                        var state = '';
                        var message = '';
                        if (result != null) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                                message += result[i] + '<br/>';
                                state += '<option>' + result[i] + '</option>';
                            }
                        }

                        $('#countrycontent').html(message);

                        $('#state').html(state); //change state's values based on selected countries

                    }

                });
            }


        });

    });
</script>
```

What I want is when there is change in country's selection state's options must change according to selected country

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use

```
$('#state').multiselect('rebuild');
```

after  `$('#state').html(state);`
maybe it will help.